# Spreadtrm Chipset. Dual Sim Application to send sms from specified sim slot. (< 22)

Tags: android, sms, dual-sim

I am tryting to develop an android application for Spreadtrum chipset smartphones. This app needs to specify which sim card (sim1 or sim2) to send sms or execute a phone call.

I was able to find an API for Mediatek [API here](http://labs.mediatek.com/site/global/developer_tools/mediatek_android/api_references/mediatek-sdk3/reference/packages.gsp), which works as an addon in android studio.

I tried to use adb shell as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007885/how-can-send-sms-in-android-in-dual-sim-with-set-default-sim). This did not work, both the commands sent sms through sim1. Two commands:

`1. service call isms 5 s16 "PhoneNumber" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "BodyText"
 2. service call isms2 5 s16 "PhoneNumber" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "BodyText"`

When I list the service calls, there are telephony.registry0 and telephony.registry1.

I tried to use reflection as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351936/how-to-send-a-sms-using-smsmanager-in-dual-sim-mobile). Sms was sent from sim1 only.

Isn't there any API or addons to use for spreadtrum

NOTE: I know this is not a prolem for Lollipop and later versions of android. But I am trying to build this application for KitKat versions.

P.S. I even tried contacting the chipset company. But sadly no response.

Comment: I am also stuck on same problem ? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use reflection for this. Following code worked for me:

```
public class SimUtil {

public static boolean sendSMS(Context ctx, int simID, String toNum, String centerNum, String smsText, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent) {
String name;

try {
    if (simID == 0) {
        name = "isms0";
    } else if (simID == 1) {
        name = "isms1";
    } else {
        throw new Exception("can not get service which for sim '" + simID + "', only 0,1 accepted as values");
    }

    try
    {
        Method method = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager").getDeclaredMethod("getService", new Class[]{String.class});
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Object param = method.invoke(null, new Object[]{name});
        if (param == null)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("can not get service which is named '" + name + "'");
        }
        method = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub").getDeclaredMethod("asInterface", new Class[]{IBinder.class});
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Object stubObj = method.invoke(null, new Object[]{param});
        method = stubObj.getClass().getMethod("sendText", String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, PendingIntent.class, PendingIntent.class);
        method.invoke(stubObj, ctx.getPackageName(), toNum, centerNum, smsText, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return true;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "ClassNotFoundException:" + e.getMessage());
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "NoSuchMethodException:" + e.getMessage());
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "InvocationTargetException:" + e.getMessage());
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "IllegalAccessException:" + e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "Exception:" + e);
}
return false;
}
}
```

For determining which isms values your sim slots carry, please view this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36235408/6013612).

For more details view this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351936/how-to-send-a-sms-using-smsmanager-in-dual-sim-mobile/30677542#).