# Unable to send SMS with Dual Sim phone in Android

Tags: android, smsmanager, dual-sim

I'm developing an Android app that sends SMS to customers, I'm using a Sony XPERIA T2 Ultra Dual with Android 5.1.1.

This is my code:

```
           SmsManager smsManager
                    = SmsManager
                        .getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(subscriptionId);

            smsManager.sendTextMessage( sms.getNumber(), null,
                                        sms.getContent(), sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

The messages are located in Messages App, but they're marked as unsent.
I' ve been trying to add message center number as scAddress param, but It doesn't work.
I tested all solutions in stackoverflow but nothing works.
Anyone has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351936/how-to-send-a-sms-using-smsmanager-in-dual-sim-mobile

Comment: Have you allowed permission in the android permissions manager for your application to handle and send SMS?

Comment: Yes! I did all but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

My app manifest was this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

But it also has to have this:

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```