# How to send sms in android app via dual sim?

Tags: java, android, sms, smsmanager, dual-sim

I successfully send a SMS through my app, but when I used dual sim mobile phones my app does not function but when I turn off other sim the message will sent successfully, I will show you my code please help me what is the way for my codes to work for dual sim phones.

I already tried Maher Abuthraa method [How to send a SMS using SMSmanager in Dual SIM mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351936/how-to-send-a-sms-using-smsmanager-in-dual-sim-mobile)

But i dont fully understand how i can implement his method it to my codings.

Timeinsms.java

```
package com.example.serviceapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class Timeinsms extends AppCompatActivity {


private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS = 1;
DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editTextId, txtphoneNo;
TextView editTextsmsi, txtMessage;
Button btngetData, btnView , sendBtn;
String phoneNo,message;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeinsms);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_idin);
    editTextsmsi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_smsin);
    btngetData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_view);
    btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_viewALL);
    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextno);
    txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_smsini);
    getData();
    viewAll();

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSMSMessage();
        }
    });

}


//////////////////SMS CODE////////////////////////


protected void sendSMSMessage() {
    phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
    message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);

                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, Timeinsms.class), 0);

        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String 
 permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("09065723958", null, message, 
null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notice:" +
                                "TIME IN SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "TIME IN failed, please try again.", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("09988456526", null, message, 
  null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TIME IN SMS 
 sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "TIME IN failed, please try again.", 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("09395393329", null, message, 
null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TIME IN SMS 
sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "TIME IN failed, please try again.", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}

//////////////////SMS CODE END//////////////////////



public void getData() {
    btngetData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String id = editTextId.getText().toString();

            if (id.equals(String.valueOf(""))) {
                editTextId.setError("Enter id to get data");
                return;
            }
            Cursor res = myDb.getData(id);
            String data = null;
            if (res.moveToFirst()) {

                data =

                        "Id:" + res.getString(0) + "\n\n" +
                                "Time In :" + res.getString(1) + "\n" +
                                "Customer :" + res.getString(2) + "\n" +
                                "Branch :" + res.getString(3) + "\n" +
                                "Machine :" + res.getString(4) + "\n";


            }
            editTextsmsi.setText("TIME IN SMS" + "\n\n" + data);
            txtMessage.setText("TIME IN SMS" + "\n\n" + data);
        }


    });
}


public void viewAll() {
    btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (res.moveToNext()) {
                buffer.append("Job No :" + res.getString(0) + "\n\n");
                buffer.append("Time   :" + res.getString(1) + "\n\n");
                buffer.append("Customer :" + res.getString(2) + "\n\n");
                buffer.append("Branch   :" + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
                buffer.append("Markss   :" + res.getString(4) + "\n\n\n");
            }
            showMessage("Time In History", buffer.toString());
        }
    });
}


private void showMessage(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.create();
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();

}

}
```

I expect the app to send a message even in dual sim phone in selected sim card only thank you so much.

Comment: Please check below link it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351936/how-to-send-a-sms-using-smsmanager-in-dual-sim-mobile

Comment: I already check the said link it is already mentioned in my questions, but I dont get how I implement it with my codings.