# Prompt user to select SIM to send SMS from Application in Dual SIM phones

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sms

I have created an App. I am sending SMS using SMSManager. But the problem is that it selects default SMS Number selected for the phone. I want to display a prompt to the user in the App itself to select SIM to send SMS before sending the SMS. Please anybody help.

---

I have tried this..... But did not work
[How to send a SMS using SMSmanager in Dual SIM mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351936/how-to-send-a-sms-using-smsmanager-in-dual-sim-mobile)

Comment: Even I'm trying to achieve the same. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not till now. I am not getting any code to send SMS via a particular SIM Port!